# Would translating my website help to get more traffic from China or Japan?

Tags: seo, translation

My website has lots of links that are linking to it from different websites, but I don't see any visitors from China or Japan.

Would translating my website help to start seeing new visitors from those countries?

Comment: Do you ask if you would attract more visitors from Japan if you have content in Japanese? Isn’t the answer obvious (as Japaneses typically speak Japanese)? What exactly makes you wonder about it?

Comment: I mean, the effect on SEO, would I benefit from english back links of english websites in the Japaneses search results? or my Japanese content get treated as if its a totally new website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, The problem of not much traffic from China and Japan is mainly because of the language barriers.

If you have a localized website, it definitely will help.

But content is always the king.

You will get more traffic from China if more of your website pages could be indexed by Baidu,

Baidu is working quite different from Google.

Comment: Please note that links to individual websites from new users aren't permitted due to issues with spam and self-promotion, which the community frowns upon.

Answer (score 1):

Are your relevant search terms are generic and popular, that are searched by users in each country in their own language? (such as, "learning French"?) Then translating it and doing some SEO work should definitely help with Baidu, which for these kind of terms shows results in Chinese.

Comment: Yes, its generic and popular, but whats the some SEO work to do also? is it important to add localized meta tags of keywords and description or the pages content is sufficient?

Comment: Of course you must change the meta title and meta description to be in the target language, and if you have any other signals for the language in your HTML you should change them as well (such as sitemaps and etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are having seo friendly keywords that are globally searches, then you need to put them in the language of the country as local people know their language only. You can change the language of your website as per country. showing keywords in their language is definitely going to help in regards to SEO. Do not forget to change the Meta tags of the site as they play an important role.